# How to embed an image on an Outlook 2007 VSTO

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto

Hi guys I am creating an Outlook 2007 add-in. I have a bunch of images in my resources folder of my project, i do a foreach on the pictures inside my resources folder and create buttons foreach item and set the buttons background to the image. Then on the buttons click i want to add the image of the button to the email body. I have this method below, but I cannot pass the IMage  object to the method i need the full path of the image.

Please advise on what to do!

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(mail.HTMLBody) && mail.HTMLBody.ToLower().Contains("</body>"))
                {
                    int mailBodyLength;
                    if (mail.Body == null)
                    {
                        mailBodyLength = 0;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        mailBodyLength = mail.Body.Length;
                    }
                    //Get Image + Link
                    Image imagePath = image;
                    object linkAddress = "http://www.pentavida.cl";

                    //CONTENT-ID
                    const string SchemaPR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID = @"http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001E";
                    string contentID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

                    //Attach image               
                    mail.Attachments.Add(imagePath, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlAttachmentType.olByValue, mailBodyLength, Type.Missing);
                    mail.Attachments[mail.Attachments.Count].PropertyAccessor.SetProperties(SchemaPR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID, contentID);

                    //Create and add banner
                    string banner = string.Format(@"<br/><a href=""{0}"" ><img src=""cid:{1}"" ></a></body>", linkAddress, contentID);
                    mail.HTMLBody = mail.HTMLBody.Replace("</body>", banner);

                    mail.Save();
                }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you save the image to the temp folder and then delete it immidiately after attaching it to the mail object:

```
using System.Reflection;
using System.IO;

//Attach image
object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

Image car = OutlookAddIn1.Properties.Resources.Car;

string path = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), "Car.jpg");
car.Save(path);

if (File.Exists(path))
  {
   mail.Attachments.Add(path,Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlAttachmentType.olByValue,missing, missing);
   File.Delete(path);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Johnnie, I believe it is only a simple error. Here is the change I have made.

```
mail.Attachments[mail.Attachments.Count].PropertyAccessor.SetProperties(SchemaPR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID, contentID);
```

to

```
mail.Attachments[mail.Attachments.Count].PropertyAccessor.SetProperty(schemaPrAttachContentId, contentId);
```